# How do I run a test with multiple sets of initial conditions?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I currently have a suite of tests which are are part of a test fixture.
I want to run the same set of tests with a different test fixture too.

How do I do this without actually having to copy-paste the tests and 'manually' changing the test fixture name (as shown below)?

```
class Trivial_Test : public ::testing::Test
{
    void SetUp()
    {
        ASSERT_TRUE(SUCCESS == init_logger());
        initial_condition = 0;
    }

    void TearDown()
    {
        shutdown_logger();
    }

    protected:
    int initial_condition;
};

class Trivial_Test_01 : public ::testing::Test
{
    void SetUp()
    {
        ASSERT_TRUE(SUCCESS == init_logger());
        initial_condition = 1;
    }

    void TearDown()
    {
        shutdown_logger();
    }

    protected:
    int initial_condition;
};

TEST_F(Trivial_Test, valid_input_1)
{
    EXPECT_TRUE(random_num()+initial_condition < 255);
}

TEST_F(Trivial_Test_01, valid_input_1)
{
    EXPECT_TRUE(random_num()+initial_condition < 255);
}
```

Is there a less verbose way of associating `valid_input_1` with both `Trivial_Test` and `Trivial_Test_01`?

P.S. - The test case shown above is a trivial test which nominally represents my actual situation but nowhere close to the complexity of the testcases or testfixtures I am actually dealing with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you consider [value parameterized tests](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#value-parameterized-tests)?

Maybe for your actual test cases it adds too much complexity, but your example would look like:

```
class Trivial_Test : public ::testing::TestWithParam<int>
{
    void SetUp()
    {
         ASSERT_TRUE(SUCCESS == init_logger());
    }
    void TearDown()
    {
        shutdown_logger();
    }
};

TEST_F(Trivial_Test, valid_input)
{
    int initial_condition = GetParam();
    EXPECT_TRUE(random_num()+initial_condition < 255);
}

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(ValidInput,
                        Trivial_Test,
                        ::testing::Values(0, 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a method in a fixture class. Here is how you would do this for you example:

```
class Trivial_Test : public ::testing::Test
{
    void SetUp()
    {
         ASSERT_TRUE(SUCCESS == init_logger());
    }
    void TearDown()
    {
        shutdown_logger();
    }
    setup_initial_condition(int value)
    {
        initial_condition = value;
    }

    protected:
    int initial_condition;
};

TEST_F(Trivial_Test, valid_input_1)
{
    setup_initial_condition(0);
    EXPECT_TRUE(random_num()+initial_condition < 255);
}

TEST_F(Trivial_Test, valid_input_2)
{
    setup_initial_condition(1);
    EXPECT_TRUE(random_num()+initial_condition < 255);
}
```

Comment: That still duplicates the testcase. My intention was to avoid testcase duplication. Something like `TEST_F((Trivial_Test, Trivial_Test_01), valid_input_1)` I imagine.

Comment: Tests should be simple and follow one assert per test rule (in most cases). Do not try to test all valid inputs in one test. In this simple example you could test several valid inputs but when you are testing something more complex then it is best ti test with only one valid input. This way, tests will be easier to debug, undestand and maintain.

Comment: @work.bin This might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240158/unit-testing-with-multiple-inputs

Comment: I get that. The tests do test only one thing at a time however I need to perform the tests under varying initial conditions. I think this is closer to what I want - https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Value_Parameterized_Tests.

Comment: Yes, it seems you want to do data-driven testing, value parameterized tests can certainly allow you to do that. However, that was not clear from your post. You were creating a new fixture class for every input value, I thought that was the issue.